# Update a existing function using stream api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the below method that I would like to rewrite using streams.

I was thinking to write a method and call that using `stream().forEach()` but not sure on how to map the return.

```
List<Student> students  = new ArrayList<>();
        if(myService.getData()!=null){
           for(Person person: myService.getData().getPersons()) {
               Student student = new Student();
               student.setGender(person.getSex());
               student.setGpa(person.getScore);
               students.add(student);
           }
        }
```

Comment: Honestly, using Streams will not improve this code.  I would leave it as it is.

Comment: @VGR I completely agree. Just that I want to make the code look cleaner. :)

Comment: I’m pretty sure it will look cleaner as you have it, than any Stream-based solution could look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) and then use the constructor to create `Student` object

```
public Student(String sex, Integer score)  {
  this.sex = sex;
  this.score = score;
}
```

And then stream the `Person` list to create `Student`

```
List<Student> students = Optional.ofNullable(myService.getData())
        .map(data->data.getPersons().stream().map(per->new Student(per.getSex(),per.getScore())).collect(Collectors.toList())
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList();
```

You can also add null check for `getPersons()`

```
List<Student> students = Optional.ofNullable(myService.getData())
        .filter(data->data.getPersons()!=null)
        .map(data->data.getPersons().stream().map(per->new Student(per.getSex(),per.getScore())).collect(Collectors.toList())
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList();
```

Comment: You don't really need an `Optional` here. The `stream` section could just replace the block within the `if`.

Comment: Since the stream operation doesn’t specify to return an `ArrayList`, there is no point in using `ArrayList` in the fallback case. Just use `Collections.emptyList()` instead.